# How can I update my question to get it reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question was closed for needing more debugging details. As you can see, I'm a new user here so don't know much about how this site works. In my question, I've provided every piece of code that might be helpful and every error message. The only strange thing is that I didn't get any comments about my question or how my question could be improved. So I guess they closed the question because a low user rep has asked a question but they can't answer it.

Here is my question:

[Failed to load resource: net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE - Audio recorder API Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148828/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-request-range-not-satisfiable-audio-recorder)

How can I make my question more helpful? I've asked for clarity about this, but no comment was given.

Comment: The one thing I think you're missing is what exactly in your code, is the last thing to run before that error occurs. What process eventually leads to the error occurring. Which parts of the code are relevant and which parts are unnecessary. There are other questions out there related to the error message you received, and they're not just jQueryJSON stuff, but things related to the same API you are using.

Comment: Other than that... i don't see anything wrong here. It's not going to be an incredibly useful question in terms of future users, but with more clarity on where in the process the error occurs in your case is all that is needed for it to be answerable. (hell, someone who's familiar with that API could probably find your issue without that. [It's been done before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362711/i-get-an-error-when-trying-to-save-a-sine-wave-audio-as-a-wav-file))

Comment: I see that davidsbro edited out the assumption about toby being targeted for being new... I'm not too sure if that is a good edit, it changes the intent of the question. For the better for sure, but that seems like the kind of edit the OP should do. Then I'll happily yank it out of my answer.

Comment: @Gimby I'll roll it back. It didn't seem important to his question based on the rest of his post.

Comment: If we closed the questions from low rep users there wouldn't be many questions. High rep users don't ask that many questions, and the ones they do ask tend to be really weird and not all that useful for a wide range of programmers. Writing a good question is hard, and if you follow a good question-asking process, crossing all the ts and dotting all the is usually finds the solution long before you hit the button and post the question. End result: There aren't that many truly good questions, but asking how to write a good question is a good early step.

Comment: Some good, general reading: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: A small note: if you had correctly tagged your question with the correct [tag:web-mediarecorder] tag I or an other subject-matter expert (SME) would have seen it and been able to reshape it in due forms. For SMEs, your question was obvious from the first revision, but for the vast majority of people that never even heard of the MediaRecorder API, it's far from being that obvious. Tagging is a very important process to attract the correct audience.

Comment: @Kaiido This should be a answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quoting from your question:

> I don't have much to say since there isn't any other information that I can provide.

Here's the other information that you can provide, which would help somebody to understand your issue:

##### What actions are you taking for the error to be produced?

As it is, if I run your code I see three buttons and no error. Presumably the error occurs when I click one of the buttons, or maybe more than one of the buttons in some specific order. Perhaps I could figure out which button(s) to press by playing around, but if I get an error by some different sequence of button presses then maybe I will write an answer that doesn't actually resolve your issue. Or if the error is specific to your browser then I might not be able to reproduce it, but I won't know whether the code is working for me or I'm just not testing it properly. Alternatively, if the error is caused by using your code in an *unintended* way, then it might just be an issue of how to make sure the user can't press the wrong button at the wrong time. We don't know!

##### What do you intend for the code to do when the error is fixed?

If the only way of judging a proposed answer is the absence of an error, then I could just delete parts of the code until there is no error. Obviously it would be silly to delete all of your code and say "there, no error!", but without knowing what the intended behaviour of your code is, I can't know whether I have made it work properly. I could guess, but I might guess wrong and then waste effort writing an answer which makes your code successfully do the wrong thing. It's far better to be explicit in the question about what the code is *supposed* to do when it works.

##### Include the full stack trace of the error

The error message alone says what the error was, but not where it occurred. For errors which occur at runtime, please include a full stack trace with line numbers.

Comment: I am not sure from where you quoted that text above - it is not (at least now) in the question of the OP. Or if it was and was deleted / edited by someone, what possible reasons could be for such deletion / editing ? I find many times the editing as not too helpful (in some cases even the OP is unable too easy to follow the changes in his original question or why they took place). This is something like "let me think and speak instead of you" attitude of someone that after doing this, he gives no more explanation and simply disappears, so you can't see him/ her later again in the conversation

Comment: @Eve It appeared in the OP's question on Stack Overflow (not the question on meta) in [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70148828/5). The OP edited their own question about half an hour ago. I think they edited it with the intention of adding the additional information outlined in my answer here on meta.

Comment: Thank you but still don't understand why for example users are required to help rephrase a question instead of the poster himself (for example the question linked in the post from this page shows a message that it does not accepting answers but instead is expecting people to ?edit? the question... Not sure to understand that. The purpose is to help the OP not to cut and mix the question transforming it in something entirely different than the initial issue. I would appreciate very much to see a comment (mostly in the original post saying why the collective editing is helpful in any way)

Comment: @Eve The question was closed because (in its original form, before the OP edited it just now) it did not meet Stack Overflow's quality standards. While closed, the question was not accepting answers. However, both the OP and other users are able to edit questions while they are closed, in practice it is usually the OP who is motivated to improve their own question, but other people are allowed to improve the question so long as they do not change the original author's intent. Edits which change the OP's intent should be rejected or rolled back, and the OP always has the power to do that.

Comment: When someone other than the OP edits a question, it is normally to improve spelling/grammar or formatting, remove "noise" that does not help people provide an answer, to replace screenshots of code with the actual code, add appropriate tags or remove inappropriate tags, or so on. This is allowed because the OP might not be familiar enough with English, markdown formatting or Stack Overflow's community standards or tag usage guidelines to make those edits themselves. In any case, the question has now been improved and reopened, so it's now accepting answers.

Comment: Do you mean just any user (above certain reputation threshold or so) can do that editing ?

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow is similar to Wikipedia in that every user in good standing is allowed to edit content (or propose edits) in order to improve it, and the community is expected to revert edits which cause harm.

Comment: @kaya3, no it does not.

Answer (score 21):

> So I guess they closed the question because a low user rep has asked a
> question

Ouch. You're off to a really bad start if you are already treating this as if people are targeting you. If you believe that then the Internet is not a safe place for you. People are judging the content, not you.

> I have researched on Stack Overflow for this type of error

Better research using a proper search engine such as Google. Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo, or whatever you prefer are far better at finding content *on* Stack Overflow than SO itself is. But there are plenty of other sites too. Like [MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs) which brings up a HTTP status code that seems to be at the heart of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/416. So that would imply a faulty header. What does your question not detail? *HTTP request and response headers*. Pretty vital information if you are asking about a request not functioning.

And yes, I agree with you, some feedback would have been nice from someone. Unfortunately providing feedback can actually blow up in people's faces as it gives a person a target to be angry at which tends to happen when questions are being downvoted or closed, because people like to believe the person giving the feedback is doing so because they are explaining a downvote or close vote they cast rather than trying to help out. So it is something people can be hesitant to do, especially with people who are new to the site.

Comment: "Unfortunately providing feedback can actually blow up in people's faces", like how all the comments on this answer were deleted, regardless of how relevant they were.